# Date convert from DD/MM/YYYY to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience, date

This will not convert my date `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyyy-mm-dd` that I send through the frontend.

**HTML**

```
<div if:true={isMobile} class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-large-size--1-of-2 padding_10">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label"><span>*</span>Date of Birth</label>
    <lightning-input 
        type="text"
        class="validValue DOB"
        placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
        pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
        variant="label-hidden"
        name="DOBMobile"
        value={dateOfBirth}
        onchange={handleDOBChange}
        date-style="short" min="1990-10-10"
        max={todayDate}>
    </lightning-input>
    <span if:true={DOBErr} class="alert-danger"></span>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
handleDOBChange(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    if (field === 'DOBMobile' && event.detail.value) 
    {
        var date = event.detail.value;
        var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
        this.dateOfBirth = newdate;
    }    
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Most likely you have a infinite loop... you handle the change... you save the value... you handle the resulting change etc

Comment: Maybe just try check if event.detail.value.indexOf('/') > -1. however, also check that the value attribute is actually a string, not a Date. It's probably best to not write to the date value - just save it in a separate variable.

Comment: i have to write the date in dd/mm/yyyy format then send that date into js as yyyy-mm-dd how can i do that

Comment: Just keep the display variable (whatever you are showing in the datepicker) - separate from the value that you are using in the Javascript controller. Write it to a separate variable. eg `dateOfBirthISO`